# Torch, how to check a variable is CUDA or not?

Tags: lua, torch

I am finding for a function like type() to identify which variable is CudaTensor or Normal.

```
require('cutorch')

x = torch.Tensor(3,3)
x = x:cuda()

if type(x) == 'CudaTensor' then -- What function should be used?
    print('x is CUDA tensor')
else
    print('x is normal tensor')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:type()` tensor's method:

```
cutorch = require('cutorch')

x = torch.Tensor(3,3)
x = x:cuda()

if x:type() == 'torch.CudaTensor' then
    print('x is CUDA tensor')
else
    print('x is normal tensor')
end
```